# How to configure pg_trgm similarity threshold parameters in a Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a Postgres database in Cloud SQL and would like to utilize the `pg_trgm` extension to do similarity searches. However, the default threshold parameters are not sensitive enough in my use case so they should be altered.

The problem is that Cloud SQL does not provide [database flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags) for either `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` or `pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold` and the database users do not have the privileges to alter the user or database:

```sql
postgres=> ALTER ROLE postgres SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.1;
ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "pg_trgm.similarity_threshold"

postgres=> ALTER DATABASE postgres SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.1;
ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "pg_trgm.similarity_threshold"
```

Is there any other way to alter these parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you do the straightforward `SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.1;`?  You would have to repeat it in every session, so maybe incorporate it into your connection sub.

For similarity_threshold, you can use the function [set_limit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) unless Google has also disabled that.  You would also have to set it this way in each session, though.  There is no alternative way to set word_similarity_threshold, though, unless Google has invented one.

Comment: It is possible to SET it so I made this a on-connection script as suggested.

Comment: You can also use a transaction level set local, which may for those using transaction pooling since session level primitives can be a little wonky there.